# angularjs directive currency formatting according to chosen translate language

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, locale, angular-translate, currency-formatting

I am formatting the a number in the format of currency, with decimals and comma/point to mark the thousands.

```
app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });
            elem.bind('blur', function(event) {
                var plainNumber = elem.val().replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

My app has two language interfaces, in German and English, which differ in the notation of numbers related to currency.
How can I take into account the language which chosen by the user so that the formatting suits the user choice?

here is my language translation code:

```
app.config(['$translateProvider',
function ($translateProvider) {    
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'assets/i18n/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });    
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');    
    $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();

}]);
```

the main controller:

```
$scope.language = {
    listIsOpen: false,
    available: {
        'en': 'English',
        'de_DE': 'Deutsch'
    },
    init: function () {
        var proposedLanguage = $translate.proposedLanguage() || $translate.use();
        var preferredLanguage = $translate.preferredLanguage();
        $scope.language.selected = $scope.language.available[(proposedLanguage || preferredLanguage)];
    },
    set: function (localeId, ev) {
        $translate.use(localeId);
        $scope.language.selected = $scope.language.available[localeId];
        $scope.language.listIsOpen = !$scope.language.listIsOpen;
    }
};

$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
    var lang = $translate.use();
    $http.get('assets/i18n/'+lang+'.json').success(function(data) {
        $rootScope.i18nTranslationJSON = data;
        $rootScope.$emit('myTranslationsLoaded');
    });
});
$scope.language.init();
```

Comment: https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale

Answer (score 0):

Have you look into the native [`$locale`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) service before trying to reinvent the wheel?
You have native filters to format currency, date and number based of the  [locale](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale) you want to use.

To change the language on the fly without reloading the page, you can use the [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) module.